# Using is_numeric to replace a string

Tags: php-8, isnumeric

In the course of converting some variables from an API, I need to check if the API is returning a string, such as "   N/A", and not a number such as  "824". This is the code that I'm attempting to use where, if the variable from the API is a number, leave it alone, otherwise, change it to a = (Zero)

```
$weather["barometer_min"] = (is_numeric($weewxapi[36]) ? number_format($weewxapi[36],0) : "0");
```

It does not appear to be working, however, it is not throwing any errors. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: `number format` should be `number_format`.

Comment: What is _"not working"_? What is your actual and expected output?

Comment: Not working means that I believe that the code should replace the "   N/A" with "0" and it does not appear to be doing that so I would like to know if my code is written right to do that or if I have made an error.

Comment: " N/A" is converted to "0". See https://3v4l.org/bSKRL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown by Syscall, using 3v4l.org, the code works.